# Binomial distribution . Heads and Tails

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Consider a coin with P(Heads) = 2/
3 . We toss this coin 100 times (assume that the tosses are
independent). Determine the probability that we get exactly 45 tails out of the 100 tosses. First, compute an
exact expression (this might require matlab or some similar tool). Next, determine an approximate numerical
value of this probability by using the central limit theorem, and the standard Gaussian table.

So I've got my $P[x]=\sum$
$_nC_x (1/3)^x(2/3)^{n-x}$

i.e $B(100,1/3)=N(100/3,200/9)$

Now what next?

Comment: you want to get 45 tails out of 100 tosses exactly , so you dont need to do the summation simply plug 55 in your expression you will get the answer !

Comment: Thanks!..But we have to use the central limit theorem , right? Hence I'm using the normal function.

Answer (score 0):

We want the probability of $45$ tails. This is given exactly by $\binom{100}{45}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{45}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{55}$. Compute, using appropriate software.

For the normal approximation, note that the number $X$ of tails has not too far from normal distribution, mean $\frac{100}{3}$, variance $\sigma^2=\frac{200}{9}$.

We should get a good approximation to the probability that $X=45$ by finding the probability that a suitable normal $Y$ lies between $44.5$ and $45.5$. The suitable normal $Y$ has mean $\frac{100}{3}$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{200}{9}}$. Compute in the usual way, using a table of the standard normal.

Comment: Amazing , this just connected the dots for me ! Thanks !

Comment: You are welcome.  Once what is happening becomes clear, things start to look easy. In the old days, one would try to avoid calculating the "exact" binomial probability, too unpleasant.

Comment: I wonder how long ago would that be :) .

Comment: In the days BC (Before Calculators). We did have electricity, but you had to rub a cat's fur to get it.

Comment: just proves that we humans aren't patient enough :). we need things done quickly and efficiently too!